# AS3 adding a function to an existing object dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var s={};
s.WHEN={}
```

Why does this work:

```
s.WHEN.foo=5;
```

but this not:

```
s.WHEN['info']=function(){trace('do something');}
```

?

after I run both these lines my s.WHEN Object has only foo:5 and is missing info:function

I use this function to see from flash through the console in the browser...

```
var console:Object={
    log:function(_){ExternalInterface.call("window.console.log",_);},
    dir:function(_){ExternalInterface.call("window.console.dir",_);}
    }
```

Then if I do (in flash):

```
console.log(s.WHEN);
```

I see:

```
Object
> foo: 5
> __proto__: Object
```

But if I do:

```
console.log(s.WHEN['info']);
```

I see:

```
function
```

Why is it there but not as part my s.WHEN object??

Comment: For me works as is , traces `function Function() {}`

Comment: yes but it's not part of my object. See above ^

Comment: This is not related to your question directly, but please do a little research on Actionscript 3 and OOP. AS3, although very similar, is not Javascript, so please try to use classes and you'll find yourself spending less time debugging these kind of statements and more time with actual logic.

Comment: Right? so am I to make a new class of object? one that holds functions?? Isn't this what an object does anyway?

Comment: Technically you're not creating a class, you're creating an instance of the `Object` class and attaching your functions to that. You're also creating anonymous functions rather than defined functions. While anonymous are supported by Actionscript-3 it is recommended to use defined functions unless necessary for the reasons [stated here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you try

```
trace( console.log );
```

You will also see `function` because you are referencing a function and not a function call.

So use :

```
console.log( s.WHEN() );
```

But you will see nothing (well, you will have a trace in Flash console) because the function referenced by WHEN return nothing.

```
s.WHEN[ 'info' ] = function(){ return 'do something' };
console.log( s.WHEN() ); // <-- Note the bracket after WHEN
```

And it will work.

But as Gio said, you should use OOP and not anonymous Object/Function, it makes life easy and debug won't be a pain.

Comment: Well I'm not just tracing with the info function. I also am tring to put other methods in s.WHEN, so calling s.WHEN() seems retarded as it should be s.WHEN['info']() as I might also later have s.WHEN['another']